# How can I get the value of specific key inside a model dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have here my model:

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel TrackAndTrace { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel MailDelivery { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel MailAccounting { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel PerformanceMonitoring { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel AdminSettings { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the value of any key of 'RoleModel'

```
public bool SaveRoleModule(RoleModel role)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(RoleModel).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
       if(property.Name != "ID" && property.Name != "RoleName")
       {
          Console.WriteLine(role[property.Name]);//(this doesn't work) I want it dynamic
          Console.WriteLine(role.TrackAndTrace); //not like this
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I used loop to shorten my code.

Comment: If you need to do this in c#, there are are possibility that you are doing something wrong or decision made based on the wrong assumptions. Can you explain why you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method here: [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) like this:

```
public bool SaveRoleModule(RoleModel role)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(RoleModel).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
       if(property.Name != "ID" && property.Name != "RoleName")
       {
          var value = GetPropValue(role, property.Name);
          Console.WriteLine(value);//(this doesn't work) I want it dynamic
          Console.WriteLine(role.TrackAndTrace); //not like this
       }
    }
    return true;
}

public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
     return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

`public bool SaveRoleModule(RoleModel role)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(RoleModel).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if(property.Name != "ID" && property.Name != "RoleName")
        {
            Type t = role.GetType();
            PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty(property.Name);
            UserRoleModel urm = ((UserRoleModel)p.GetValue(role, null));
            // do something with urm
        }
    }
    return true;
}`

Though Fabio is right, this does seem strange and potentially based on faulty reasoning.